# c# Outlook Add-in get Sent date after email is in Sent mailbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I have made an Outlook Add-In (Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-In) for business purposes to save the email details to our database. The add-in is launched when a new email is composed, but closes when the email is sent.

The sent date of the email is only added after the email is moved to the Sent mailbox. Is there a way to use my current add-in (or another add-in) can be used to get that sent date after it has been closed without letting the user wait for it to be moved to the sent mailbox?

I know it can easily be done in VBA, but I want to preferably use an Add-in so that it can be easily loaded to all users with exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that date be today's date/time (Now) or something close to it?

Everything you can do in VBA you can do in a COM addin - subscribe to the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder and retrieve the date when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dmitry for the reply. It set me on the right path. I used my existing VSTO add in to fire when a new item is added to the Sent mailbox. I did not know that when inserting this in the "ThisAddIn_Startup" method re-activates the add-in, which now makes sense.

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx) example.

Here is my code:

```
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
Outlook.MAPIFolder Sent_items;
Outlook.Items items;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Sent_items = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

    items = Sent_items.Items;
    items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
}

void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;       

    string strMailItemNumber_filter = mail.UserProperties["MailItemNumber"].Value;

    if ((Item != null) && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strMailItemNumber_filter)))
    {
        if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note" &&
                   mail.UserProperties["MailItemNumber"].Value.ToUpper().Contains(strMailItemNumber_filter.ToUpper())) //Instead of subject use other mail property
        {
            //Write 'Sent date' to DB
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sent date is: "+ mail.SentOn.ToString()+ " MailNr = "+strMailItemNumber_filter);

        }
    }

}
```

I had to create a new mail user defined property to match the email I sent to find the correct email in the sent mailbox:

```
        private void AddUserProperty(Outlook.MailItem mail)
    {
        Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
        Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;
        try
        {
            mailUserProperties = mail.UserProperties;
            mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("MailItemNrProperty", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
            // Where 1 is OlFormatText (introduced in Outlook 2007)
            mail.UserProperties["MailItemNumber"].Value = "Any value as string...";
            mail.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mailUserProperty != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperty);
            if (mailUserProperties != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperties);
        }
    }
```